# Filling Page With Images

Tags: css

I have a page that I've created that has images across it. They all have the same the same width but different heights. I want them to fill the empty spaces between them. Kind of how a tumblr layout works, but so there is only the margins I set between the height and width.

So the question is really.

How do I make it so I can put images in a div and have them fill all the space between them except my predetermined margins if they all have a set width?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a good way to do this in pure CSS (yet).

Take a look at isotope.js http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Yeah! Exactly but how do you do that? Is it just float left, or?

Comment: Masonry is another good library that does this.  Take a look at the documentation for each library mentioned, they're both well written.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you'll be very happy with Masonry, see here: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Read the introduction, check out some examples and you'll get it right away:
http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html